# String stream comes up empty

Tags: c++, string, integer, append, stringstream

I've been trying to append an integer to a string, and I've tried several solutions here, including:

```
std::stringstream ss;

ss << gvHours << "\'" << gvMinutes << "\"" << gvSeconds << ":" << gvTicks;

std::string output(ss.str());
return output.c_str();
```

and

```
std::stringstream ss;
std::string output = "";

ss << gvHours << "\'" << gvMinutes << "\"" << gvSeconds << ":" << gvTicks;

output = ss.str();
return output.c_str();
```

The first one gives me an empty string, and the second gives me an unreadable character that Notepad++ displays as "SOH" in a black box. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope. It's likely the cause of your problem. And depending on how you view the string, it could be empty simply because it consists of invisible characters. For example, SOH is the "Start of Header" control character (ASCII code 2).

Comment: Why would you return a C-string anyway? lol

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this part

```
return output.c_str();
```

is broken.

When you take `c_str()` from a `std::string`, you are just getting a c-style pointer to the contents of that string. But you are *not* getting *ownership* of the data underlying that string. As soon as you return from the function, that stringstream and string are destroyed (as they are local variables) and the `c_str()` is a dangling pointer. So the whole thing is undefined behavior.

Comment: So then, should I make a pointer to a new const char* and return that instead?

Comment: @KelvinShadewing, Returning a `std::string` is the most obvious advice to give, but I assume you have a reason for not doing that.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. Here's the code I got that works:

```
std::stringstream ss;
std::string output;

ss << gvHours << "\'" << gvMinutes << "\"" << gvSeconds << ":" << gvTicks;

output = ss.str();
return output;
```

And in the function where it was needed:

```
fprintf(gvLog, ">: %s\n", timeString().c_str());
```

Comment: Note that you have no way of deleting this dynamically allocated string object. You leak one string per call.

Comment: Edited. That should fix the memory leak, I think.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help!